# LaTeX tables: How do I make thicker or thinner horizontal lines (typically \hline)?

Tags: tables, rules

The title says it all:

In LaTeX tables: How do I make bold horizontal lines (typically `\hline`)?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Your question suggests that you might be interested in setting tabular rules (`\hline`'s) of different weight in order to improve your typography rather than for the purposes of some simple "one-off" adjustment. If so, you should consider the [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package (if you haven't already done so). It provides canned weighted rules (`\toprule`, `\midrule`, etc) which, for typographical reasons, are defined in terms of fractions of `em`'s rather than `pt`'s, although these are very easy to define in `pt`'s as well.  Each rule can be locally or globally parameterised for your own specific weighting requirements. The package also provides macros like `\heavyrulewidth` and `\lightrulewidth` which you can use "as is" or can redefine to suit your particular needs. (Just as the author uses the term 'rule' where others might call it 'line', the author also uses the term 'width' where others might prefer to use 'thickness'.) The package is exceptionally easy to use. As a side-benefit, the documentation contains some very insightful guidelines about the ins and outs of good tabular typography.

Comment: I think this is the cleanest solution, however for this document I was already using tabularx tables and do not have the time to switch to booktabs :(

Comment: @JCL: strange, `tabularx` and `booktabs` should co-habitate quite well.

Comment: @levesque: Geoffrey is right — it's important to note that booktabs is not a new tabular environment; it provides "rules" to use in whatever tabular you're currently using.

Comment: After having really experimented with booktabs, I see that you both were right ;) It really does not imply much work to start using them!

Answer (score 69):

```
\usepackage{makecell}
```

and use e.g.

```
\Xhline{2\arrayrulewidth}
```

instead of `\hline`

Comment: This works wrong for longtable.

Comment: @IvanBychkov: This does work for `longtable`. You should use `makecell` after `longtable`.

Comment: @LeoLiu - great...this solution was the only one working straightforward!

Comment: It does not work well with longtable: the bold line does not reach the border, it stops before and continues with a normal line. Odd.

Comment: for `{tabular}` env it worked great as I was already using the `{makecell}` pkg

Comment: Can we also define color of line?

Answer (score 46):

You can also fix the default tickness of `\hline` or use a`\specialrule` also from `booktabs` or `ctable` package. (Since the `ctable` package imports `booktabs` packages, all commands from this package are available as well). This is a MWE:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable} % for \specialrule command

\begin{document}
\centering

Default \texttt{\textbackslash hline}: 
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

Thicker \texttt{\textbackslash hline}: 
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.3em}
\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

Custom \texttt{special rule}s with  \texttt{ctable} package: 

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\specialrule{.05em}{1em}{0em} 
 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\specialrule{.1em}{.05em}{.05em} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\specialrule{.2em}{.1em}{.1em} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\specialrule{.3em}{.2em}{.2em}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\specialrule{.4em}{.3em}{.3em}
1 & 2 & 3 \\    
\specialrule{.5em}{.4em}{.4em}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\specialrule{.6em}{.5em}{0em}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It s useful for me right now!

Answer (score 17):

```
\def\hlinewd#1{%
\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height #1 %
\futurelet\reserved@a\@xhline}
```

and then use `\hlinewd{2pt}` in your tables, for instance.

This should compile:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\makeatletter
\def\hlinewd#1{%
\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height #1 %
\futurelet\reserved@a\@xhline}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hlinewd{2pt}
plo & plo & plo\\ \hlinewd{2pt}
plo & plo & plo\\ \hlinewd{5pt}
plo & plo & plo
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the following error message :" ! You can't use `\spacefactor' in internal vertical mode.
<recently read> \spacefactor ".






Is there a package that I need to include?

Comment: where did you put this definition? don't forget \makeatletter \makeatother when necessary.

Comment: With my other environment (re)definitions, before the begin document. I don't use the @ character anywhere else in my document than in that definiton.

Comment: I just edited the message above.

Comment: This works wrong for longtable.

Comment: Could be. I never tried.

Comment: @pluton nice solution. It worked for me. This is especially useful when you use \rowcolors which can easily override the default \hline and make it invisible unless you use high magnification like 400%. Also, with booktab package you get a band of white space around \hline which I am guessing won't work with colored rows.

Answer (score 13):

I suggest you use the `\specialrule` command of the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package, but should read the containing paragraph in the manual. Such a thick rule is generally frowned upon (especially in scientific texts).

An example could be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{rccc}
        \toprule
        Thing & Value & Value & Value\\
        \midrule
        A & 1 & 2 & 3\\
        B & 1 & 2 & 3\\
        C & 1 & 2 & 3\\
        \specialrule{2.5pt}{1pt}{1pt}
        D & 1 & 2 & 3\\
        E & 1 & 2 & 3\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

A simple solution for completeness sake: setting the length register `\arrayrulewidth` with `\setlength` allows you to globally set the width of the line produced by `\hline` if you place it outside of the `tabular` environment.

Changing `\arrayrulewidth` inside `tabular` however doesn't seem to work.

---

## Example document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
  \hline
  A & B & C & D
  \\\hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4    
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

## Example document output:

[image: Sample document output]

Comment: If you put it outside `tabular` but within `table`, i.e. between `begin{table}` and `begin{tabular}`, it works fine

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with `tblr` and `booktabs` environments of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package: you can set widths and colors for hlines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{rccc}
    \hline[2pt,red5]
    Thing & Value & Value & Value\\
    \hline[1pt]
    A & 1 & 2 & 3\\
    B & 1 & 2 & 3\\
    C & 1 & 2 & 3\\
    \hline[1pt]
    D & 1 & 2 & 3\\
    E & 1 & 2 & 3\\
    \hline[2pt,blue5]
\end{tblr}

\bigskip

\begin{booktabs}{colspec={rccc},row{odd}={blue9}}
    \toprule
    Thing & Value & Value & Value\\
    \midrule
    A & 1 & 2 & 3\\
    B & 1 & 2 & 3\\
    C & 1 & 2 & 3\\
    \specialrule{2.5pt,teal5}{1pt}{1pt}
    D & 1 & 2 & 3\\
    E & 1 & 2 & 3\\
    \bottomrule
\end{booktabs}

\end{document}
```

[image]