# Booktabs and longtable - strange spaces between lines

Tags: tables, longtable, booktabs

I needed to make some horizontal table lines bold so I used booktabs package. However if I use `\toprule` command to make line bold I get strange outcome - there are some spaces between bold line and vertical table lines (please take a look at screen )
[image]

code used to generate table looks this way

```
    \begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\caption{Wyniki rozpoznawania obrazów dla obrazu zapytania 022\_0007.jpg oraz kategorii $budda$}
\label{tab:budda}
\\
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Obraz zapytanie}} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Obraz przetwarzany}} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Wynik}} \\
\toprule
\textbf{Nazwa} & \textbf{N} & \textbf{Katalog} & \textbf{Nazwa} & \textbf{N} & \textbf{ $J_{b}$} & \textbf{$J_{a}$} & \textbf{Czas[s]} & \textbf{Gęstość} \\ \hline
...
..
..
\end{longtable}
```

PS
Is it possible to make horizontal lines bold ??

EDIT
I decied to resign from booktabs and I used solution presented in here 
[LaTeX tables: How do I make thicker or thinner horizontal lines (typically \hline)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3445/latex-tables-how-do-i-make-bold-horizontal-lines-typically-hline) (pluton answer)
now I have a horizontal  bold lines and I also managed to make vertical lines bold. The problem however is horizontal line length. My table's length is a bit bigger than length of page (from one margin to another) and I think it makes the horizontal lines look like that
[image]

Is it possible to somehow adjust this command

```
    \def\hlinewd#1{%
\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height #1 %
\futurelet\reserved@a\@xhline}
```

so that it adjust length of the bolded line to the length of the table

Here is compilable code snipet

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{mwrep}

\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=3.0cm,right=3cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[centerlast]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[section] {placeins}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\linespread{1.3}
\makeatletter
\def\hlinewd#1{%
\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height #1 %
\futurelet\reserved@a\@xhline}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{somechapter}
\section{somesection}
\small
\begin{longtable}{!{\vrule width 2pt} c!{\vrule width 2pt} c!{\vrule width 2pt} c!{\vrule width 2pt} c!{\vrule width 2pt} c!{\vrule width 2pt} c!{\vrule width 2pt} c!{\vrule width 2pt} c!{\vrule width 2pt} c!{\vrule width 2pt} }

\caption{something something somethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomething}
\label{tab:budda}
\\ \hlinewd{2pt}
\multicolumn{2}{!{\vrule width 2pt}c!{\vrule width 2pt}}{\textbf{Query image }} & \multicolumn{3}{c!{\vrule width 2pt}}{\textbf{Processed image}} & \multicolumn{4}{c!{\vrule width 2pt}}{\textbf{Outcome}} \\ \hlinewd{2pt}

\textbf{Name} & \textbf{N} & \textbf{Directory} & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{N} & \textbf{ $J_{b}$} & \textbf{$J_{a}$} & \textbf{time[s]} & \textbf{Density} \\ \hlinewd{2pt}
022\_0007.jpg   &   193 &   budda   &   22\_0007.jpg    &   193 &   25512.9 &   156.1   &   288.5   &   0.73    \\  \hline  
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The booktabs package is explicitly designed for tables *without* vertical rules. So either you should redo your table without vertical rules, (generally preferred) or not use booktabs rules.

Comment: Further to @Alan's comment: This is taken from the [`booktabs` documentation](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) (p 3):
"You will not go far wrong if you remember two simple guidelines at all times:
 1. Never, ever use vertical rules.
 2. Never use double rules."

Comment: @AlanMunn please see my edit

Comment: @imagePlacer for all intents and purposes, it's impossible.  Probably not literally so, since very little in TeX is truly impossible it seems, but in practical terms, yes, you can't use booktabs rules with vertical lines. To give another quote from the docs: "More importantly the rules generated by the [booktabs] commands are in no way guaranteed to connect with verticals generated by {|} characters in the preamble. This is a feature (see above). You should not use vertical rules in tables, end of story." (p.5)

Comment: @imagePlacer It would help you make your new edit have a complete, compilable minimal document which produces just the output you are having trouble with. That way people can see what you are doing without having to guess.

Comment: @AlanMunn I added compilable code snipet which presnet the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I  finally found a solution for making booktabs and hrules work so that is why I make an answer to my own question
I created my own command

```
\newcommand{\mytoprule}{\specialrule{2pt}{0em}{0em}}
\newcommand{\mybottomrule}{\specialrule{2pt}{0em}{0em}}
```

and now everyting looks fine.

Comment: This works even better with \bigstrut to help with the cramped row heights.

Answer (score 2):

To your second question:

the `\midrule[width]` has an optional argument for the line width and should at least leave the same space above and below the line.

With the command `\cmidrule[width]{columns}` you can add a horizontal line with defined width that spans not all columns.

See `booktabs` [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) for more information.

AFAIK you can not suppress the vertical spaces easily, as they are part of the "philosophy" of `booktabs` (not to use vertical lines at all) and they make the difference between the `toprule` and the `bottomrule`.

example for line width for a midrule with very thick lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable, booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\caption{Wyniki rozpoznawania obrazów dla obrazu zapytania 022\_0007.jpg oraz kategorii $budda$}
\label{tab:budda}
\\
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Obraz zapytanie}} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Obraz przetwarzany}} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Wynik}} \\
\toprule
\textbf{Nazwa} & \textbf{N} & \textbf{Katalog} & \textbf{Nazwa} & \textbf{N} & \textbf{ $J_{b}$} & \textbf{$J_{a}$} & \textbf{Czas[s]} & \textbf{Gęstość} \\ \hline
…\\
new line\\
    \midrule[2 pt]
new line\\
\cmidrule[5pt]{1-5}\\
..
..
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please use CTAN addresses as `http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/...`

Comment: @Martin please see my edit :)

Comment: The length of the line (whether via `\hline` or `\hlinewd`) defaults to `\hline` which stretches across the entire length of the table. If it protrudes into your margins, then the actual *table* is too wide, not the *line*. You need to either adjust the `\@extracolsep{...}`, or resize the entire table to fit within the margins: `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}}`.

Comment: @Werner Are You sure that resizebox works with longtable ? I don't understand Your answer. You wrote that \hline as well as \hlinewd should strech across entire length of the table, however only \hline is streched but \hlinewd is too short. I added compilable code snipet which presnets my problem

Comment: @imagePlacer: I missed your use of `\begin{longtable}`, sorry. No, resizing of a `longtable` is not possible, since it is meant to flow across pages. Also, I see now that your `\hlinewd` uses `\hrule`, not `\hline`. `\hrule` exists only within `\linewidth`. So, as soon as the end of the line is reached, `\hrule` stops, hence the gap from the right margin to the right edge of your `longtable`.

Comment: I've added an answer that modifies `\arrayrulewidth` to `2pt` which should help if all lines are the same width in your `tabular`/`longtable`.

Answer (score 1):

By using

```
\renewcommand{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}%
```

you can drastically improve readability of your code and produce the desired effect (assuming, of course, that all your rules - vertical and horizontal - are the same width). The advantage is that is also works with `longtable`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{mwrep}
...
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
\chapter{somechapter}
\section{somesection}
\small
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\caption{something something somethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomething}
\label{tab:budda}
\\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Query image }} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Processed image}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Outcome}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{N} & \textbf{Directory} & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{N} & \textbf{ $J_{b}$} & \textbf{$J_{a}$} & \textbf{time[s]} & \textbf{Density} \\ \hline
022\_0007.jpg   &   193 &   budda   &   22\_0007.jpg    &   193 &   25512.9 &   156.1   &   288.5   &   0.73    \\  \hline  
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Setting tabular rule thickness/width]