# Table Design Help

Tags: tables

I'm trying to mimic the design of this table:

[image]

Any advice?

Comment: Can you perhaps specify where the difficulties lie, which element of the table you are not able to reproduce?

Comment: I can't replicated the first "column" that has Model 1 and Model 2

Comment: The first row you mean? (Rows are horizontal, columns vertical.) `\multicolum{5}{c}{\textbf{Model 1: Total sample}` will create a centered cell that spans five columns

Comment: Do you want the data to be input from a file, or will you be typing all of the numbers into the .tex file?

Comment: I use EViews if that helps

Answer (score 2):

In Order to mimic the design of this table, you will need:

- `booktabs` for the horizontal lines (`\cmidrule` for the shortened versions; [See here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3449) for bold lines)
- `multicolumn` for the headings (e.g. for your first row `\multicolum{5}{c}{\textbf{Model 1: Total sample}`)
- `siunitx` for numbers aligned with their decimal points (see the `S` column), or `numprint` (`n` and `N` column types)
- `\textbf{}` for bold text and `\textit{}` for italic text and/or
- `makecell` to have a global formatting of specific cells, using its `thead` and `makecell` commands
- `arydashln` for the dashed horizontal lines, though I think `midruule` from the booktabs package would look better.
- `caption` for the bold caption (and search this side on how to achieve "Table F" instead of "Table 1.1"
- Some time to typeset all this

Maybe you need packages like `pgfplotstable` if you like to input your data with `.dat` or `.txt` or `.csv`-files.

All of this packed in a `tabular` environment. If you are having concerns about the small ticks below the fourth horizontal line, you should write (or search for) an own question on this topic. However, the documentation of `booktabs` (Terminal - `texdoc booktabs`) shows easy and beautiful ways to go without such things.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a `multicolumn` example, cf. the comments to the question.

Comment: This table is not so well done: the headers in the `variable` line are misplaced with respect to the numbers in their columns.

Comment: @Bernard just add it to my answer. `S` column with `{\emph{coeff}}` would be right, I guess.

Comment: @Larifari: I would raher use the `thead` command, from `makecell`: you can declare globally font characteristics,  alignment (vertical and horizontal) and vertical spacing in the preamble. Your didn't mention the `arydshln` package for the dashed line, though I suspect it was employed in place of a thinner line as `booktabs` provides.

Comment: @Bernard Don't know this. But pls feel free to edit.

Comment: LaRiFaRi, in my table when I use \textbf{} on some of the numbers, these numbers are no longer aligned by the decimal point. Any help?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2766/siunitx-aligning-numbers-by-decimal-points-in-tables-doesnt-work-for-bolded-or

Comment: Or for single values http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66253/siunitx-bold-single-numeric-cells. Please use the search function on this page. I found these two and others in seconds.