# Increase width of caption's horizontal lines in algorithmic and listings

Tags: tables, listings, algorithmic

I've been able to increase the width of the horizontal lines honoring the second answer in [LaTeX tables: How do I make thicker or thinner horizontal lines (typically \hline)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3445/latex-tables-how-do-i-make-bold-horizontal-lines-typically-hline).
Now, I'd like to do the same in algorithmic & listings environment but I don't know how to do that. Is that possible? and if so, how?

For instance, the following example

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\blah}{blah blah blah blah blah\\}
\newcommand{\hlinethick}{\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}}

\blah \blah \blah

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=tb]
    return 1;
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{My algorithm.}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Algorithm}{}
    \State \textbf{return} $mat$
    \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\blah \blah \blah

\begin{table}
  \begin{center}
  \caption{My table.}
    \begin{tabular}{c r r r}
    \hlinethick
      header1 & header2 & header3 \\
    \hline
      $T_{s}$              & 7 & 14 & 21 \\
      $T_{i}$              & 3 &  3 & 20 \\
    \hlinethick
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

Comment: Regarding `listings`, see section 4.11 in the doc: the `framerule` key controls the width of rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `listings` package provides a key called `framerule`, which takes a dimension value (e.g. `2pt`) and determines the thickness of rules that used in listings.

Changing the thickness of rules used in algorithms is more complicated. The `algorithm` package delegates the drawing of those rules to the `float` package, which doesn't allow the user to tweak the thickness in any straightforward fashion; instead, the thickness is hardcoded in the definition of so-called *floatstyle*s. Therefore, your only option is to redefine the *floatstyle* of interest (the default one, `ruled`, here).

For convenience and better maintainability, I've defined a new length macro (called `\hrulethickness`) that governs the thickness of rules used in tables, listings, and algorithms of your document. See below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{makecell}

% one length to rule them all
\newlength\hrulethickness
\setlength\hrulethickness{4\arrayrulewidth}
\newcommand{\hlinethick}{\Xhline{\hrulethickness}}

% `listings' settings
\lstset{framerule=\hrulethickness}

% redefinition of the `ruled' floatstyle
% (defined in the `float' package, used by the `algorithm' package)
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\fs@ruled{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@ruled
  \def\@fs@pre{\hrule height \hrulethickness depth0pt \kern2pt}%
  \def\@fs@post{\kern2pt\hrule height \hrulethickness depth0pt \relax}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\kern2pt\hrule height \hrulethickness depth0pt \kern2pt}%
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\blah}{blah blah blah blah blah\\}
\blah \blah \blah

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=tb]
    return 1;
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{My algorithm.}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Algorithm}{}
    \State \textbf{return} $mat$
    \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\blah \blah \blah

\begin{table}
  \begin{center}
  \caption{My table.}
    \begin{tabular}{c r r r}
    \hlinethick
      header1 & header2 & header3 \\
    \hline
      $T_{s}$              & 7 & 14 & 21 \\
      $T_{i}$              & 3 &  3 & 20 \\
    \hlinethick
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```